# How can I capitalize a character with an odd-numbered index in a string?

Tags: python, string

So I was doing our exercise when I came across capitalizing characters in odd indices. I tried this:

```
for i in word:
   if i % 2 != 0:
       word[i] = word[i].capitalize()
   else:
       word[i] = word[i]
```

However, it ends up showing an error saying that not all strings can be converted. Can you help me debug this code snippet?

Comment: Can you add a full traceback of the error

Comment: You should study about immutable objects in Python. As strings are immutable, you can't edit it `word[i] = word[i].capitalize()`.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is strings in python are immutable and you cannot change individual characters. Apart fro that when you iterate through a string you iterate over the *characters* and not the *indices*. So you need to use a different approach

A work around is

- (using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate))

  ```
  for i,v in enumerate(word):
     if i % 2 != 0:
         word2+= v.upper()       
         # Can be word2+=v.capitalize() in your case 
         # only as your text is only one character long. 
     else:
         word2+= v
  ```
- Using lists

  ```
  wordlist = list(word)

  for i,v in enumerate(wordlist):
     if i % 2 != 0:
         wordlist[i]= v.upper()  
         # Can be wordlist[i]=v.capitalize() in your case 
         # only as your text is only one character long.

  word2 =  "".join(wordlist)
  ```

A short note on `capitalize` and `upper`.

From the docs [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize)

> Return a copy of the string with its ***first character capitalized*** and the rest lowercased.

So you need to use [`upper`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) instead.

> Return a copy of the string with ***all the cased characters*** converted to uppercase.

But in your case both work accurately. Or as Padraic puts it [across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317937/how-can-i-capitalize-a-character-with-an-odd-numbered-index-in-a-string/29317967?noredirect=1#comment46828580_29317967) *"there is pretty much no difference in this example efficiency or output wise"*

Comment: The else is redundant in the second example, if you are not capitalising then you are not changing

Comment: Oh Yeah!. That was spot on! :)

Comment: Dear downvoter, do leave a comment below the post explaining the problem in the code. I will be really interested in correcting myself!. Thanks

Comment: `.capitalize()` is the wrong way to make a string upper case use `.upper()` instead

Comment: @XavierCombelle Thanks for the feedback. If you could mention as to why, I would be more than grateful to you

Comment: @BhargavRao, there is pretty much no difference in this example efficiency or output wise.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Added a small explanation just in case

Comment: @BhargavRao, capitalize will make `"foo"` `"Foo"` that is the only real difference between the two .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah! So it does not matter in the OP's case. However if some future guys have a look... So just added it. :D Have left a small comment to the OP. Should I add any other note?

Comment: Looks fine, I would not worry about   the downvotes for using  `.capitalize()`, that is the least relevant part of the answer. The logic is the important part.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Well, `.capitalize()` will also make `"FOO"` `"Foo"`, so it seems weird to me to use it here. (But I didn't dv).

Comment: @PM2Ring, yes upper is probably the right thing to use, my point was it is secondary to the main problems and certainly not worth downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

You need enumerate and capitalise any character at any odd `i` where `i` is the index of each char in the word:

```
word = "foobar"

print("".join( ch.upper() if i % 2 else ch for i, ch in enumerate(word)))
fOoBaR
```

`ch.upper() if i % 2 else ch` is a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) where we change the char if the condition is True or else leave as is.

You cannot `i % 2` when `i` is the actual character from the string, you would need to use range in your code or use enumerate and concatenate the changed characters to an output string or make words a list.

Using a list you can use assignment:

```
word = "foobar"
word = list(word)
for i, ele in enumerate(word):
   if i % 2:
       word[i] = ele.upper()

print("".join(word))
```

Using an output string:

```
word = "foobar"
out = ""
for i, ele in enumerate(word):
    if i % 2:
        out += ele.upper()
    else:
        out += ele
```

`if i % 2:` is the same as writing `if i % 2 != 0`.

Comment: `.capitalize()` is the wrong way to make a string upper case use `.upper()` instead

Comment: @XavierCombelle, it makes very little  difference to the output and you are commenting on  probably the least relevant part of the answer

Comment: it's for making a better answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would change word letters in a word or a sentence to uppercase

```
word = "tester"

letter_count = 1
new_word = []
for ch in word:
    if not letter_count % 2 == 0:
        new_word.append(ch.upper())
    else:
        new_word.append(ch)
    letter_count += 1

print "".join(new_word)
```

if I wanted to change odd words in a  sentence to uppercase I would do this

```
sentence = "this is a how we change odd words to uppercase"

sentence_count = 1
new_sentence = []
for word in sentence.split():
    if not sentence_count % 2 == 0:
        new_sentence.append(word.title() + " ")
    else:
        new_sentence.append(word + " ")
    sentence_count += 1

print "".join(new_sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help...

```
s = input("enter a string : ")
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    if(i%2!=0):
        s = s.replace(s[i],s[i].upper())  
print(s)
```